# RSpec runnning in loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I need to make such changes to a Rails 5.1 app, so as the first thing I run the Rspec suite (version 3.7) and it runs forever.

Everything works fine if I run individual subfolders, i.e. `bin/rspec spec/models`. Also, a dry run works as expected `bin/rspec spec --dry-run`(the entire suite draws almost 7 lines of dots) [image]

However, when I run the entire suite `bin/rspec spec` it runs forever.

[image]

I have also changed a spec to fail and, as you can see, it's executed twice.
When I try to kill the process with `ctrl + C` it takes a very long time before it actually ends.

Any ideas what is going on here?

UPDATE - The issue seems to be related to `system` specs, if I rever them to features everything works fine.

Comment: Try to run the suite with the same seed passing the `-fd` option, to see if it's running again the same examples and/or where is getting stuck.

Comment: It's running and running ......
It runs once (I suppose) with the document formatter and now running (multiple times) with the porgress formatter.